# How can I style just the submit button with CSS?

Tags: css, forms, button, submit, styling

So I want my submit button to be a different width than my other input fields.  I am trying to do this but the submit button still has the same width.  Please Help!
Here is my CSS:

```
     #logon {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 60%;
        top: 10px;

    }
    #logon input { 
        display: inline;
     border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: #bebebe;
width: 150px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;

text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;

    }
        #logon input.button { 
        display: inline;
     border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: #bebebe;
width: 50px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;

text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;

    }
```

And my HTML:

```
     <div id="logon"><form action="login_r.php" method="POST"> <input name="myusername" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Username..." /> <input name="mypassword" type="password" size="40" placeholder="Password..." /><input type="button" value="Log In"></form></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct attribute selector is:

```
#logon input[type='button']
```

However, if you're submitting a form, it should be `<input type="submit" />`, in which case you want

```
#logon input[type='submit']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.button` selector is for the **class** "button".  Your `<input>` element doesn't have a class on it. You can try this:

```
input[type=button] { whatever }
```

Personally I like `<button type=submit>` better than `<input type=submit>` because it's a lot more flexible in terms of content (things like little icons etc).

Comment: He doesn't seem to have a type=submit button

Comment: @cheesemacfly oh you're right; I saw it but I forgot after I started typing :-)